# Difference between "at" and "on" option of schedule in LocalNotification in ionic capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, localnotification

Can anyone please explain to me what is the difference between using "at" and "on", because the purpose I feel similar? Just the writing style of date is different?

````
export interface LocalNotificationSchedule {
    at?: Date;
    repeats?: boolean;
    every?: 'year' | 'month' | 'two-weeks' | 'week' | 'day' | 'hour' | 'minute' | 'second';
    count?: number;
    on?: {
        year?: number;
        month?: number;
        day?: number;
        hour?: number;
        minute?: number;
    };
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'at' means you have to set the notification on that specific date you have no other option, whereas, with 'on' you can say, i want it on year 2014 or i want it on day 15. You have multiple options with 'on', with 'at', you have only one.

Meaning, for 'at' on that specific date it will be triggered, but for 'on', once you set it at day = 15, each day 15 of the month it would trigger.

Comment: Thank you, Just need more clarification here. For example, I am setting the year 2014, So how many times or on which day and time it will generate the notification.

Comment: 'on' is commonly used for repetition purposes.

Comment: if you set it to year 2014, then it would trigger on the first month of that year and the first hour and day of that year.

Comment: So If I want to stop the repeat. How can I do it now, because it is like repeating for forever?

Comment: You have the count property.